# Disable or hide links with a specific class or ID for specific users

Tags: php, css, wordpress, class, woocommerce

I have a webpage where I want to either disable or hide two specific links in the nav menu for customers who haven't purchased the product. Is this possible to do with PHP? I am new to PHP and have never used it before, so apologies for the messy and non functional code below that I am currently using. The first part for identifying a paid customer should work thanks to a reply I got here on Stack overflow.

Basically, I am trying to achieve this through two scenarios:

1. I have an existing CSS class of my link (in this case 'google-link') that I am trying to change and name differently if the user has or hasn't purchased the product. I would then style that class in CSS differently.

OR

2. Is it possible to target just the nth-child of this class and apply those changes ONLY to that nth-child in PHP? E.g. that I have a class 'google-link' that's applied to all nav menu links, but I only want to be able to change it for the 3rd element, so to use PHP for something like google-link a:nth-child(3)

This is what I am currently using:

```
function disable_links( $class) {

$class= 'google-link' ;

    if( isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) ){
        $user_data = get_user_by(is_email( $_POST['username'] ) ? 'email' : 'login', $_POST['username']);
        $user_id = $user_data->data->ID;
        $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value'  => $user_id,
            'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
            'post_status' => array('wc-completed','wc-processing')
        ) );
        if($customer_orders){
            // Purchased user
            $class = 'disabled-link' ; 
        }else{
            // Non purchased user
            $class = 'normal-link' ; 
        }
    }
    return $class;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'disable_links' );
```

Comment: you can target the page-item class there is each item has different page-item-{id}

Comment: `:nth-child` can not be combined with a class selector. But if _all_ of your links have that same class, then `:nth-child` alone will do. Only you will most likely not be able to apply it to the `a` elements directly - because such a menu is usually not just plain link after plain link, but the links are usually wrapped into `li` list item elements within a list. So you would need to target the 3rd `li` element, and then you can format the link that contains.

Comment: Your approach to check the POSTed username and password makes rather little sense though - because with that, this would only work for the next page that is shown after these login credentials have been processed. As soon as you navigate to the next page, these POST parameter obviously won't exist any more. You should just use `get_current_user_id()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work using the following code, so hopefully it could help someone :)

```
function hide_menu_conditional($items, $args) {
        // Check if the USer is logged in
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value'  => $user_id,
            'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
            'post_status' => array('wc-completed','wc-processing')
        ) );
        if($customer_orders){
                    return $items;
        }
        else{
            foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
                if ($item->title == 'My course') {
                    // Remove the menu item
                    unset($items[$key]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'hide_menu_conditional', 10, 2);
```